# Checking for null when using like over multiple columns in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following sql query to do a basic text search on some column data.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE ((id||author||title||selftext||url||media||comments) LIKE '%teacher%')
```

Each column contains either text or null as a value. How would i go about making sure I only run `LIKE` on non null values?

I tried the following without success:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (id IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (author IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (title IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (selftext IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (url IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (media IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%') OR (comments IS NOT NULL AND LIKE '%teacher%')
```

Comment: `id LIKE '%teacher%'` is enough. There is no need to check if id is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (id IS NOT NULL AND id LIKE '%teacher%') OR (author IS NOT NULL AND author LIKE '%teacher%') OR (title IS NOT NULL AND title LIKE '%teacher%') OR (selftext IS NOT NULL AND selftext LIKE '%teacher%') OR (url IS NOT NULL AND url LIKE '%teacher%') OR (media IS NOT NULL AND media LIKE '%teacher%') OR (comments IS NOT NULL AND comments LIKE '%teacher%')
```

Comment: `id LIKE '%teacher%'` is enough. There is no need to check if id is null.

Comment: yes true id like '%teacher%' is enough did not realise it